# couchbase - [Errno 113] No route to host

Tags: docker, couchbase

I am trying to setup a Couchbase container using Docker on a CentOS machine. I installed the couchbase server but when i init a cluster via the following command i get  [Errno 113] No route to host

```
couchbase-cli  cluster-init -c 1.2.3.4:8091 --cluster-init-username=admin --cluster- 
init-password=couchbase --cluster-init-ramsize=512

ERROR: command: cluster-init: 1.2.3.4:8091, [Errno 113] No route to host
```

But the Couchbase server URL -

```
http://1.2.3.4:8091
```

gives me a Couchbase home page with the setup button on the right bottom.

Answer (score 0):

It was a small issue. In the Dockerfile - if i try to access the couchbase host with IP, i am getting "No route to host" error but when i try "localhost" it works fine. Its a temporary fix i found as of now.